# What is the /media/username squashfs volume?

Tags: media, squashfs

I just noticed this volume showing up in files. Is this some new backup system in Ubuntu? On 21.10. Had not seen it before. Searched online but no good hits so far.

Comment: Squashfs is a filesystem that is used on bootable live/install Linux distribution USB/SD-devices. It is a compressed (squashed) file. It contains the OS and programs that it will unpack/install when told to when you boot from that USB/SD device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing it too,

Opening gnome-disk-utility (Disks), it refers to it as /dev/loop8, so it's a loop device (a file mounted as volume/file system) and it's file is /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_14549.snap (deleted), so it's a snap related loop device.

The file doesn't exist at that location anymore as Disks indicates.

Logs only say this:

Mounted /dev/loop8 at /media//disk on behalf of uid 1000

/dev/loop8: Can't open blockdev

I'm thinking it's a snapd or a specific snap problem. Maybe a snap, like firefox or calc, etc. crashed and left it. I'm also thinking it'll go away with a restart or logout. But I usually have uptimes of a week or more and don't want too logout right now either so I'm gonna leave it.